# Writing a correct URL.py and template for django with hyperlinks involved

Tags: django

Am following along on the django tutorial (1.6 python 3.3). Am however stuck in trying to replicate the tutorial in my own test application.

I want to display a list of just 3 hyperlinks on the index page. The hyperlink for now is just the name of listed item.

**Views.py**

```
def Index(request):
    tables = []
    tables.append('Country')
    tables.append('County')
    tables.append('Registration Body')
    return render(request, 'test_app/index.html', {'table_list': tables})
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from test_app import views
urlpatterns = patterns('test_app',
    #url(r'^Country/', views.Index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.Index, name='index'),
)
```

**Index.html**

```
<h1>List of Config Tables in TestApp</h1>
{% if table_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for tbl_name in table_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'test_app:index'  tbl_name%}">{{ tbl_name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <ul> 
        <p>No table found<p>
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

With that setup, I get the error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /test_app/
Reverse for 'index' with arguments '('Country',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['test_app/$']
```

Something weird is that when I get rid of the `tbl_name` in href in the index page I am able to get my list but the list DOESN'T have hyperlinks.

Comment: You don't allow parameters in your views and URL. But you pass a param to your view function. You should add it, or just remove tbl_name from URL in template.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. In the Index View am passing the mandatory `request` object. Should I pass something else? Also, if I remove the `tbl_name` from URL in template, how will I get a hyperlink that looks like this `http://test_app/country/` or `http://test_app/county/`? Please elaborate.

Comment: In URL, you can write *^/(?P<name>.+)/$*. And in views, *def index(request, name)* . Name will be the tbl_ name

Comment: Ok. Its worked fine with your suggestion. However, I didn't add the extra variable in the view.... so it looks like it wasn't necessary? I need to reread the docs or something coz even if its worked, I haven't understood the concept and its bugging me

Comment: A question that I have is if the hyperlink is being evaluated when Django is loading the index page or when I actually click on the links? I would have thought having only `url(r'^$', views.Index, name='index'),` would be enough to load the index page only?

Comment: When you load the page or click the hyperlink, both will evaluate. When you load the page directly, you did not put a param in URL, so it works well. And when you click hyperlink, you pass a param, so raise an error. Actually I didn't understand your question well. You can take a look document, may there are better answers. Thanks